# REST API learning curve

Tags: php, ajax, rest

I'm a newbie to the back-end, trying to build a REST API. I'm having trouble retrieving my request data from the ajax call.

```
<?php
$logfile = fopen("log.txt", "w");
fwrite($logfile, "testing\n");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$req_dump = print_r( $input, true );
fwrite($logfile, $req_dump . "\n");

fclose($logfile);
?>
```

My call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://example.com/api.php",
  data: {data:"data"},
  success: function(){ console.log('success'); }
});
```

My log.txt file just gets the text "testing", but nothing to indicate the passed object {data:"data"}. What steps am I skipping here?

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: try to call this php script using a tool like https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: and remove the close php tag '?>' of the  script

Answer (score 1):

The ajax what you're doing is a `get request` and the object data is being sent as a query string in the url: `/api.php?data=data`, data sent as a query string in php are stored in `$_GET`

Try this:

```
<?php

$logfile = fopen("log.txt", "w");
fwrite($logfile, "testing\n");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
//$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
$input = json_encode($_GET,true);
$req_dump = print_r( $input, true );

fwrite($logfile, $req_dump . "\n");

fclose($logfile);
```

Comment: Alfredo, that works perfectly! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1981130, if Alfredo's answer was helpful, please accept it.